# C# Make Control Use All Available Vertical Space

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, spacing

I have a DataGridView and I would like to know if it's possible to make it fill all available vertical space (not horizontal as well). If there is not enough space, a vertical scroll bar should be displayed. It currently looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The weight goes up to 500, but it cuts off at 210. This is what happens when I set DataGridView.AutoSize = true.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the `Dock` or `Anchor` properties.

Comment: @SLaks I've tried DockStyle.Top, DockStyle.Left, AnchorStyle.Top and AnchorStyle.Left, but none of them make a difference.

Comment: You need to dock left or right or anchor to top and bottom.  (and also for the parent container, if any)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w8z0xh4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte

Comment: Well, make `AutoSize = false` since you want to control the height yourself.  The Dock or Anchors should work then and the scrollbar should appear.